# What does object configuration means?

Tags: spring

I read this statement many times

> The IoC container is responsible to instantiate, configure and assemble the objects.

I understood instantiate, assemble is like injecting dependencies.

so what does this configure means?

Answer (score 0):

Full sentence would be something like The IoC container is responsible to instantiate, configure and assemble the objects by reading configuration metadata provided. The configuration metadata could be by XML or by Java annotations or by Java code itself. The Spring IoC container uses Java POJO classes and (specified) configuration metadata to produce a fully configured and executable system or application. Hope It will make clear for you.

Answer (score 0):

For example, a Data Source could be an instance of JDBC data source. And it is 'configured' to point to say mysql server hosted on your localhost accessible using a certain port, user, password configurations.

Certain configurations can be separated from object construction (say default constructor using reflection and then setting configurable properties on the created object.)